# Duplicate records on joining

Tags: postgresql, order-by

I have two tables `books` and `books_data`. `books` can have multiple `books_data`, `books_data` can have only one `book`. `books_data` table has `date` column by which I want to sort the `books` table. When trying to do this, the code returns duplicates. But the duplicates appear only when trying to paginate results, e.g. if I provide `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0` for first query and `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20` for the second, some of the records from first query will appear in the second query too. If I specify `LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0` there are no duplicates. Here's my query (it may be not perfect, because it is generated by Rails ORM Active Record):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "books"."id", "books_data"."date" FROM "books"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "books_data" ON "books_data"."book_id" = "books"."id"
ORDER BY books_data.date DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `books.id` to `ORDER BY`. If `books_data.date` is not unique, relative order of rows in resultest is not guaranteed. Say you have 5 rows with date1, 10 rows with date2, and 5 with date3; date1 < date2 < date3.

Then some rows with date2 may appear on both pages, some on neither, and , if you are lucky enough, you may sometimes see expected results.
Assuming (books.id,books_data.date ) ***unique*** the following should return consistent results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "books"."id", "books_data"."date" FROM "books"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "books_data" ON "books_data"."book_id" = "books"."id"
ORDER BY books_data.date DESC, books.id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Short illustration :

```
id | some_non_unique_data  
1  |  'val1'  
2  |  'val2'  
3  |  'val2'
```

When splitting such data into 2 pages, 2 rows per page ordering only by `some_non_unique_data` ascending the engine is free to return row id=2(or id=3) on any page. *emphasized text*

Comment: @ Dima Knivets : you have DISTINCT keyword, so book.id+date are unique; `order by` unique value is consistent - in my example tuple "id=2,  some_non_unique_data = 3" is always 'before' "id=2,  some_non_unique_data = 3" (surely when id included in `order by` clause)